# How to save current point of angular controller after refresh browser page

Tags: angularjs

I have some variables in angular controller. I have there if user is logged in and other details . When i am refreshing my page using `f5` all my variables are reloading and i am getting in log in page, but before refresh i was already logged in and my variable `isUserLoggedIn` was `true` but after refresh it is `false` , `false` is this variables default value, I am declaring it in Controller .How can I save all my variables ( current point of angular controller ) and continue with my saved point after refresh ?

Comment: you can use localstorage

Comment: how can i do it using code can you tell me ? Can you explain it in more details ?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: you can use cookies, localstorage or sessionstorage of browser to store data

Comment: if i use `localstorage` like @Sachin Gupta said too, how can i catch refresh event to restore my variables from this `localstorage` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browsers local storage(HTML5) and store your data.

E.g:
to write:

```
$window.localStorage['sample-key'] = 'sample-data;
```

to read:

```
var data = $window.localStorage['sample-key']
```

There are many libraries available for this, you can check this one:
https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: I must save all my variables like this ya ? For example `$window.localStorage['userLogedIn']=true ; $window.localStorage['variable1'] = false;` and so on , but where can i write this code ? how can i catch refresh event ?

Comment: you don't need to catch refresh event, as it is stored in browser itself.

Comment: yes but where can i locale this code ? and how can i know if my page has already refreshed and i must take data from `localStorage`, if i don't need to catch refresh event ?

Comment: I think you should first take a look at local storage, how it works. then I think it would be good for you to use it.